# How to enable network tracing in .NET on mono?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

I'm trying to log all outgoing HTTP requests and responses a .NET application makes. I am following this article from the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

I am providing a short example of my code and app.config.
The following works as expected and produces a file `network.log` which includes the full request and response body. However this only works on Windows and .NET Framework. Running the same code on Linux using mono version 5.18.1.0 - `mono Program.exe` does not create the `network.log` file and does not throw any exception.

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace TraceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="System.Net"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="System.Net"
              type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="network.log"
              traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime"
      />
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true"/>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Is there any way to log all network traffic on Mono from the application itself? I do not want to run an external program to capture the traffic.

Comment: 1. On Linux you should use .NET Core instead of Mono now. 2. That tracing was only implemented in .NET Framework on Windows. Mono does not have an equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. We are in the process of migrating to .NET Core but for now the application is still ran using mono. Is there any alternative way to achieve the same thing?